# Entity Framework 6 Code first One-to-Many relation in 3rd level child tables

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

I have *`ApplicationUser`* table created by ASP.NET identity framework and want to use another table Customer with `one-to-one relation`. The `PK` of `ApplicationUser` table is `Id` of type string. And the `Customer` table has a `FK` of type string. I am not allowed to change the `Id` type for `ApplicationUser` table. But customer table must have an identity(auto number) column with int type. This is fine.

And then this `Customer` table has a `one-to-many` relation with `Contact` table. 
[image]

Both `Customer` and `Contact` tables have unique identity column `Id`s. The `Contact` table has a `CustomerId` Column. If there is no `AspNetUser` table, code first generates `one-to-many` relation using these `id` and `CustomerId` columns. Since the `AspNetuser` table has `one-to-one` relation with `Customer`, this doesn’t use `CustomerId`. But the code first generate its own string key `(Customer_UserId)` to build this `one-to-many` relation.

How do I use `Customer` table column to relate `Contact` tables `CustomerId` column to map the relation using EF6 code first approach?

Here is the complete code:

**ApplicationUser**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    //Navigation   properties
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

**Customer**

```
public class Customer
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public string BusinessName { get; set; }

    //Navigation properties
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

**Contact**

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string OfficeLocation { get; set; }
    //Navigation properties
    [Required]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

}
```

**ApplicationDbContext**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(): base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false){}

    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        // Set the database intializer which is run once during application start
        // This seeds the database with admin user credentials and admin role
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .HasRequired(u => u.ApplicationUser).WithRequiredDependent(c => c.Customer);
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WebServer.Models.Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WebServer.Models.Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  `ApplicationUser` and `Customer` tables are `one-to one` so the both tables has the same `PK` (`String Id` in `ApplicationUser` and `String UserId` in `Customer`). Logically we can think these two tables as one table with `PK` of type `string`. 
The `Contact` table is a child of `Customer` table. Therefore `one-to-many` relation between `Customer` and `Contact`. Therefore `Contact` table must have a `Foreign Key` of type string. So the `CustomerId` in the model should be type of `string` instead `int`. Also to instruct code-first to use this field I need to add `[ForeignKey("CustomerId")]` attribute to `public Customer Customer { get; set; }` property.

So the new Contact model should be like this

```
public class Contact
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string CustomerId { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string OfficeLocation { get; set; }

   //Navigation properties

   [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
   [Required]
   public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

PS: In my original application I have another level in this table hierarchy. A contact can have many address, so the `Address` table can use `FK` of type `int` with `Contact`s `PK` to form another `one-to-many` relation.

Answer (score 0):

I found that removing your explicit foreign keys and also removing the contact's 'Customer' property changed the schema significantly.

This removes the `Customer_UserId`.

Looks like this is the behaviour you are after.

Comment: If you do that only EF generated diagram shows it as `one-to-one` and breaks `one-to-one` relation in the SQL server . And also if I remove the `[Key, ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]` and `[ForeignKey("UserId")]` from the `Customer` table it will create another column called `ApplicationUser_Id` to relate with `ApplicationUser` table. I do not want to do that. 

If I only remove only  `Customer` property from the `Contact` table it will create `zero-or-one` customer to `many` contact relation and adds `Customer_UserId` to contact again, it is also not the result what I want.

Comment: I see what you're after now. Looks like you'll need to set some keys on the existing base `IdentityUser` properties. Will update my answer later.

Comment: I did notice that you've got the UserId in the Customer table being set as a primary key. That breaks your model for one.

Comment: if the `string UserId` is not the PK then it will not relate one-to-one with `ApplicationUser` since it has string Id as the PK. That we do not want to change. You can create a test project using Package Manager with `PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples -Pre`. More info [here](http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/04/20/ASPNET-Identity-20-Setting-Up-Account-Validation-and-Two-Factor-Authorization.aspx). And then add the models given above to try it out. Then you will get a better understanding about my problem.